# How to draw a line In a Android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I draw a line it may be horizontal or vertical in an ANDROID Activity in Run time
Can any one say how to do this . . . .
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see here [link][1]
and 

[here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android/12987068#12987068
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990244/drawing-a-line-with-canvas-from-an-activity

Comment: post what you did for the same

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal:

create a view `tag()` in the xml layout with `width = "match_parent"` and `height="1dpi"`

For vertical:

create a view `tag()` in the xml layout with `height= "match_parent"` and `width="1dpi"`

Don't forget to set background color

If u want to hide it and then show it from java, like on click of a button or something then set its visibility to invisible with `android:visibility` attribute , and then get this view by id in the java class and set its visibility to visible by `myView.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.please have a look on the following link:
       http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=canvas-draw-line-android